# Off Fails On Live Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to unbind all events attached to elements inside a container using JQuery's off function however it is doing some odd things.

My code is as follows

```
<div id='container'>
<button id='test_btn'>Test</button>
<button id='live_btn_id1'>Action</button>
<button id='live_btn_id2'>Action</button>
</div>

$("#test_btn").on("click", function(){
$("#container").find("*").off();
});

$("#container").on('click', 'button[id^=live_btn]', function(event) { 
alert("hello");
});
```

The result of this is that the test_btn correctly stops working however the 'Action' buttons continue to work. However if I do the following:

```
$("#container").off();
```

It works as expected but that also removes my stuff I have attached to container. Is there a reason for this odd behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use delegation you are binding to the element, not the descendant selector.

So you call `$("#container").on(...` and you are binding to `#container`, not `live_btn`.

`.off` on `live_btn` would not make sense because nothing is bound to them.

A possible solution is to namespace the click event:

```
$("#container").on('click.live', 'button[id^=live_btn]' ...
$("#container").off('click.live');
```